# Angular 4: npm start throws error

Tags: angular, webpack

I am using `angular 4.4.4`, `webpack 3.8.1`, `@angular/compiler/cli 4.4.4` (after upgrading)

After upgrading my node module packages using `ncu - npm check updates`
I get this error

> /home/razmjo/workstation/jobsaf-website/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:71
>               throw new Error('Must specify "tsConfigPath" in the configuration of @ngtools/webpack.');

Even though I have set `tsConfigPath`  properly according to this:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/packages/%40ngtools/webpack

**Update**: configuration files (I have removed lots of things for the sake of clarity)

```
const AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AotPlugin;
module.exports = function (options) {
  return webpackMerge(commonConfig({env: ENV}), {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          loader: '@ngtools/webpack'
        },
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new AotPlugin({
        tsConfigPath: 'tsconfig.webpack.json',
        entryModule: 'src/app.module#AppModule',
        sourceMap: true
      }),
    ],
  });
}
```

Comment: can you show us the configuration file?

Comment: please see update

Comment: the tsconfig isn't right! You must provide the default tsconfig config.

Comment: you mean 'src/tsConfig.json', I did that, does not work.